# Conditional Excel formula based on existing value in adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

So I have an excel sheet.
I want ColD to contain a formula that, when ColC to the left contains an "@" symbol, ColD will fill with a certain text. It would exclude Row1 as that contains headers.

Not really sure how to do this, is it possible?

Comment: give a proper example with real data sample and [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell D2:

`=IF(COUNT(FIND("@",C2))>0,"Certain Text","")`

Comment: Cool. That works well for a single cell, how do I apply it to both columns though?

Comment: Copy it into each cell in column D ("Fill Down" works)